# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project - how install a file in alternate path?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I'm new to setup proj in vs2008.
I need to know how to configure a file in my setup project, so that it is installed to a specific location other than the install directory.

example: main install directory = c:\program files\etc..

this other file: install directory = c:\mydirectory\myfile.txt

There is probably a simple solution, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: I found where to enter the custom path  (View > Editor > File System : right click - add special folder), but I'm now getting an error on install : Installer Error 2714 Invalid value for default folder name: [2]. but it's a valid folder name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was a complete bonehead on this one. The problem is that I was entering the path into the (Name) property instead of the DefaultLocation property.